# Is there are alternative to robot programming game robocode?

Tags: java, robocode

I dont mind if it will be turn based or real time. It just must be popular and allow to write your strategy with java language

Comment: Hi! I don't understand your question... The Robocode seems to be in .NET and Java. From their website: "Robocode is a programming game, where the goal is to develop a robot battle tank to battle against other tanks in Java or .NET. The robot battles are running in real-time and on-screen."

Comment: It is fine if it support other language. But I want examples which support java as one of the languages.

Comment: Just to be sure: you want something else but in Java as well, right? Because Robocode seems to be famous and it is in Java. You can even compile your own Robocode "Arena" with Eclipse: http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode/Developers_Guide_for_building_Robocode

Comment: Yes, I have fun with robocode and now I want something new :)

Comment: I will be interested by an example of what Robocode is capable :) In the same kind of idea, not in Java, there are several Core War games: http://www.corewars.org

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was [TORCS](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/) but it's not in Java. However, it looks like you [can write cars/logic with Java](https://code.google.com/p/tappstorcscar/).